# Flask / Python NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Tags: flask

I've tried a lot of recommendations from similar questions, but cannot seem to figure out why "main.py" is not recognizing "app". Thanks in advance for any help!!

innit file

```
from flask import Flask
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    return app
```

main file

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)


@main.route('/')
def index():
    print(app.config['CUSTOM_VARIABLE'])
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `app` object cannot be imported and is therefore not accessible. You can use a proxy object called [`current_app`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.current_app) to get the configuration.

```py
from flask import Blueprint, current_app, render_template

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    print(current_app.config['CUSTOM_VARIABLE'])
    return render_template('index.html')
```